# Forbidden access to nagios

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, forbidden

Having a 403 error after connection to Nagios. I use ldap auth, and this part is working, but when i'm logging on, i always get the 403 forbidden access.

*nagios apache conf :*

```
# SAMPLE CONFIG SNIPPETS FOR APACHE WEB SERVER
# Last Modified: 11-26-2005
#
# This file contains examples of entries that need
# to be incorporated into your Apache web server
# configuration file.  Customize the paths, etc. as
# needed to fit your system.

ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"

<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/sbin">
#  SSLRequireSSL
   Options ExecCGI
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
#  Order deny,allow
#  Deny from all
#  Allow from 127.0.0.1
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
   AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.1.1.220:389/OU=UsersVDB,DC=vdb,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(memberOf=*******)
   AuthLDAPBindDN cn=******
   AuthLDAPBindPassword ********
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Nagios Access LDAP"
   Require valid-user
</Directory>

Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"

<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share">
#  SSLRequireSSL
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
#  Order deny,allow
#  Deny from all
#  Allow from 127.0.0.1
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
   AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.1.1.220:389/OU=UsersVDB,DC=vdb,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(memberOf=C*********)
   AuthLDAPBindDN cn=************
   AuthLDAPBindPassword *********
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Nagios Access LDAP"
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

In my httpd.conf, have :

`ErrorLog logs/error_log`

Don't know why but can't have information output when accessing in my error log...

```
[Wed Apr 27 09:30:04 2016] [debug] proxy_util.c(1929): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Apr 27 09:30:04 2016] [debug] proxy_util.c(2025): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 16583 for (*)




*Was the blank i've put to separe the nagios log and the other*
```

What can i do ?

Comment: You tagged this apache-2.4, but you're using allow/deny which is 2.2 syntax. Also, you don't use `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative` with 2.4.

Comment: yes, my fault, it's apache 2.2

Comment: Have you tried ```LogLevel Debug``` ?

Comment: Yes, i've tried warn and debug, and there is no result in the 2 case